# Date filter using DURING predicate in Common Query Language

Tags: java, geoserver

How do I apply date range filters in common query language using predicate like DURING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporal predicates specify the relationship of a time-valued expression to a time or time period. The syntax is:

```
Expression DURING Time Period
```

> Describe - Tests whether a time value is during a time period

for eg :

```
ts DURING 2016-02-26T00:00:00.000Z / 2017-02-27T23:59:59.999Z
```

where "ts"is time expression(or key name holding datetime value)

for more information on duration based queries for Temporal Predicate refer the following link
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#temporal-predicate